# remove all white space in a input text field before bindrequest

Tags: symfony

well, just as the title of the question, anyone can help? i means all the white spaces not before and after the string. I just see the trim option  to true and this is not what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony internally handles this with an EventListener.  I should imagine that you can steal this technique for your own purposes.

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Form\Extension\Core\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\FilterDataEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class StripWhitespaceListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
  public function onBindClientData( FilterDataEvent $event )
  {
    $data = $event->getData();

    if ( is_string( $data ) )
    {
      $event->setData( preg_replace( "/\s/", "", $data ) );
    }
  }

  static public function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return array( FormEvents::BIND_CLIENT_DATA => 'onBindClientData' );
  }
}
```

And then, in your form type's `buildForm()`

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilder $builder, array $options )
{
  $builder
    ->add( 'foo', 'text', array( 'label' => 'Foo' ) )
  ;

  $builder->get( 'foo' )->addEventSubscriber( new StripWhitespaceListener() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this should work fine. alternatively, i write a JavaScript before submit the form.